# What is the most efficient SQL query to do the following?

Tags: sql

What is the most efficient SQL query to do the following?

Following are the two tables joined on ItemID:

Item { ItemID, OtherData }

Love { ItemID, Username }

I pass in a "someuser" as Username in the query.

Query should return ItemID, OtherData, and a boolean indicating whether there exists a Love for the ItemID.

Comment: `Like` is not advised to be table name, as it's a reserved word.

Comment: Are you looking for a query or a LINQ statement? The linq tag has me a bit confused.

Comment: Either works, but solution has been found!

Comment: What's your teacher gonna think when he/she finds this?

Comment: lol, this is not for school, but for a project I'm working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT Item.*
       ,CASE WHEN t.ItemID IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS flag
FROM Item LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ItemID FROM Love WHERE Username = someuser) t
        ON Item.ItemId = t.ItemId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT I.ItemID, I.OtherData, CASE WHEN L.ItemID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Loved FROM Item I LEFT JOIN Love L ON I.ItemID = L.ItemID
```

To the op stop changing your requirements!

Comment: I'm looking for all items, and not just items with Likes

Comment: I didn't change the requirements though. I just changed the table name as suggested. But this query looks promising. Is it the most efficient though?

Comment: For something this small and trivial this is the simplest way to get what you want.

Comment: I think this is on track. Could you elaborate on your solution a little bit to help me understand what's going on exactly? As I understand it now, you're left joining all the loves to the items, and then testing if love.ItemID is there or not to set the boolean. This solution currently does not take the "someuser" username into account though.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT i.ItemID, i.OtherData
FROM Item as i
INNER JOIN Like as l ON i.ItemID = l.ItemID
WHERE Like.Username = {someuser}
```

If there is no Like for ItemID then i.ItemID will be NULL, you can test for that condition as your boolean.